# Window 8 retrieve HTML content

Tags: c#, windows-8, httpwebresponse

Here is a simple function to retrive the html content from a website. So people can extract the data from it. 
i only found Window 8 have http webservice to get html. and found this way only. if anyonehave better way please share.

```
 protected  override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
            {

                gethtml("URL");
            }

            public async void gethtml(string URL)
            {
                HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
                WebResponse myResponse = await myRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                mainTxtBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();  
            }
```

Since window 8 only httpwebrequest only have "GetResponseAsync" i have to use await. and for  away only in async function. async function only return Task<> or void. and after that to change from Task<> to other format is so confuse and messy. So i make it return void and transfer data to other global source.
I dont find any simple explaination how to get string from Task. So i use this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your `gethtml` should return `Task` not `void`. Only async event handlers may safely return `void`.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    await gethtml("URL");
}

public async Task gethtml(string URL)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    WebResponse myResponse = await myRequest.GetResponseAsync();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    mainTxtBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();  
}
```

However, I would put it like this:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    mainTxtBox.Text = await gethtml("URL");
}

public async Task<string> gethtml(string URL)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    WebResponse myResponse = await myRequest.GetResponseAsync();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    return sr.ReadToEnd();  
}
```

Comment: +1 for the "However" part. UI should only be changed in the UI thread